# Kubernetes golang libraries dependency problem

Tags: go, kubernetes, compiler-errors, dependencies

I am compiling first kubernetes project with golang.
https://github.com/hubenokdev/kuber_simple
But I have some dependencies problems when compiling.

And I have some questions in go.mod,
After the command 'go mod tidy', you can look following line in go.mod
require github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-lib-external-provisioner v4.1.0+incompatible

but sig-storage-lib-external-provisioner`s latest version is 9.0.0.
How could you explain this and how fix above problem?

I typed as following:

go mod init hello.go
go mod tidy
go build